# Unicode glyphs for wysiwyg ruler bar symbols (margin, left-tab,right-tab, center-tab and decimal-tab)

Tags: unicode, special-characters

Various word processors and text layout software have a "ruler bar" to indicate margins, indentation, and tab locations for a block of text. The symbology used in ruler bars is fairly consistent across manufacturers: an upward pointing triangle for a margin stop, a downward pointing triangle for the first-line indent, and an assortment of right angles and inverted T's for right-tab, left-tab, center-tab and decimal-tab.

Are there official Unicode code points for these symbols? If not, what code points would best represent them?

Comment: Have you reviewed Unicode symbol lists, such as this one https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/table/ ?